# Do statuses given to Dangers affect future rolls against that Danger?

Tags: city-of-mist

Do statuses given to Dangers affect future rolls against that Danger?

For example, if a player is fighting a thug and that thug currently has the status *brusied-1*, could that plausibly affect a future ***Go Toe to Toe*** favorably for the player if it's against that target?

Comment: I'm still learning the system, but doing a demo session for some of my players it seemed as though it may be easy for players to create the death spiral effect on enemies—that is, the more you inflict statuses on them the easier it gets to inflict statuses on them—and I was wondering if I was playing that incorrectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Effects of Statuses on Dangers, MC Toolkit, p.128:

Statuses on Dangers do (only) ONE of three (MC's choice):
- contribute to overcoming the Danger (counting against its spectrums)
- apply to player moves against the Danger
- weaken/strengthen the Danger's moves

Therefore, when a status contributes to a Danger's defeat (e.g., bruised-2 on its Hurt spectrum) it doesn't also improve players moves against that Danger (when Going Toe to Toe, bruised-2 doesn't also add 2 to the Power) -- it EITHER leads to its defeat OR applies to player moves against it.